# Upload file using Express failed : “cannot read property file of undefined”

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to upload a file with a form like this (JADE) :

```
form(action="/file-upload", name="upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    input(type="file", name="theFile")
    input(type="submit", name="Upload")
```

this is my app.js :

```
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.multipart());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

and this is how I handle the requests:

```
app.post('/file-upload',function(req,res){
   console.log('FIRST TEST: ' + JSON.stringify(req.files));
   console.log('second TEST: ' +req.files.theFile.name);
});
```

and this is my Node.js Console :

```
FIRST TEST: undefined
TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'theFile' of undefined....etc....
```

oh and by the way there is a warning from Connect module :

```
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
```

What am I do wrong here ? i have follow advise from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480568/nodejs-and-express-error-when-uploading-file-cannot-read-property-of-undefined), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959708/req-files-not-working-node-js-express), [here](http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads) with nothing works. Thanks for help.....

UPDATE: 
i just added LOGGER to my apps with result, so it's seems that i got the request:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Wed, 19 Feb 2014 11:02:11 GMT] "POST /file-upload HTTP/1.1" 500 - 
"http://localhost:3000/admin/news-add" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Express has an example for file upload [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/multipart/index.js) and according to it it looks like your doing things right on the server backend. Try adding `app.use(express.logger('dev')` to enable some log output to see what you are actually receiving.

Comment: just add logger as you suggested. it seems fine, server got the POST request and still 'undefined'

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959708/req-files-not-working-node-js-express

Answer (score 3):

I see now... i have

```
app.use(express.multipart());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

after `app.use(app.router);` where it should be declared before, like this :

```
app.use(express.multipart());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride())
app.use(app.router);
```

now, it's work like a charm....