# Send multiple files from front end to POST method

Tags: javascript, java, file, attachment, email-attachments

Here is my Code sample: https://jsbin.com/qokiyomivu/edit?html,js,output

How can I send multiple files to my POST method and then attach these with email from the Java method?
Currently if I select multiple files only one is being sent and attached to the email written in the Java method. How to attach all I select ?

FYI, I have declared filesToUpload as MultipartFile like `private MultipartFile filesToUpload` in my Bean.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a good question that I myself have spend some time to refine to a good solution.
I came out with:

```
$('#filesToUpload').change(function(e) {
                $.each(e.currentTarget.files, function(i, file: File){
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onprogress = function (event) {
                        'do something'
                    };
                    xhr.onloadend = function(event){
                        var status = (<XMLHttpRequest>event.target).status;
                        if (status != 200) {
                            console.error(String.format("Server did not return a 200 but: {0}.", status));
                        }
                        else
                            'upload completed';
                    }
                    xhr.open('POST', 'urlpath', true);
                    xhr.send(file);
                });
            });
```

Thsi will upload yout files on every change - but my main purpose by showing this code, is to guide you towards `XMLHttpRequest`.
If you have large files, there are a technology to chunk up your data, but that takes a bit af work to get up running.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Kenneth for your time. Really appreciate it. In fact I want to send files to my POST method upon press of a submit button. Then in that method I want to attach the files with some email text. Currently one file is being attached even I am trying multiple files. Thanks again, can you pls help me?

Comment: There is a good example on that right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035977/upload-multiple-files-with-xmlhttprequest-to-express-js-3-5-server