# I am trying to receive video file and save it on the server with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to receive a video file and save it in the uploads folder with the right extensions using node, express, and multer. I know my video is getting passed to the server correctly but it isn't saving how I would like it. This is my backend code.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var multer = require("multer");
var app = express();
var path = require('path'); 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// this is cors this allows my angular app to call this node backend even though they are both on local host 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
// here I am calling multer to get the filename of the file I am serving up specifying what folder I want it to go in
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (request, file, callback){
         callback(null, './uploads');
     }, 
     filename: function(request, file, callback){
         console.log(file); 
         callback(null, file.originalname)
     }
 }); 

 var upload = multer({storage: storage}); 
// this app.post calls the post method this is where I will upload the file
 app.post('/upload', function (request, response) {
     upload(request, response, function(err) {
         if(err) {
             console.log('Error Occured'); 
             return; 
         }
         console.log(request.file);
         response.end('Your file Uploaded'); 
         console.log('Video Uploaded'); 
     })
 }); 
// my app is listening on localhost port 8080 for the post to be called
 var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
     console.log('Listening on port ' + server.address().port) 
 });
```

this is my error

```
c:\toolbox\pos-estate-data\oneops\ScoSopBackend>node app.js
Listening on port 8080
TypeError: upload is not a function
    at c:\toolbox\pos-estate-data\oneops\ScoSopBackend\app.js:29:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\toolbox\pos-estate-data\oneops\ScoSo
pBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (c:\toolbox\pos-estate-data\oneops\ScoSopBackend\node_modules\expres
s\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
```

client side code

```
upLoad() {
    let strSopName : string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("sopName")).value; 
    if(strSopName == "" || strSopName == null || strSopName == "Error you must enter a sop name"){
        strSopName = "Error you must enter a sop name"
        return;
    }

    this.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:8080/upload", [], this.filesToUpload).then((result) => {
        console.log(result); 
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    }); 

}

makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var formData: any = new FormData(); 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name); 
        }
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4){
                if(xhr.status == 200){
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                }else {
                    reject(xhr.response); 
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.open("POST", url, true); 
        xhr.send(formData); 
    })
}
```

html

```
<br>
                <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" name="videofile" placeholder="upload file..." class="form-control" id="Video" accept="video/mp4, video/x-m4v, video/*" required>
           <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't properly initialising `multer`'s `upload` middleware. That's why experiencing `type error`.

In your case, you want to upload single file, try the following initialisation and replace `'file'` with `input` `name` related to file in `form`

e.g.,

You have `input` tag of `type="file"` with `name="videoFile"` in `form` in your `html`

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="videoFile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then, you can initialise `multer` to pull `file`

```
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('videoFile');
```

Please note that it is name of `input` tag that receives `file`, not `filename` itself.

**EDIT**

As discussed in comments, you are uploading multiple files.
Try

```
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).array('uploads');
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: what if I do not know what the file name will be. I am eventually wanting to allow people to upload videos to my server. I have no idea what the video name will be.

Comment: I want the name to be whatever they choose to name their video

Comment: I updated the answer with clear description. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: this got me past that error but now I am just receiving a generic error when I submit. because in my code if(err) console.log error occurred. I tried to do console.log(response) it gave me info like the file was coming through

Comment: 36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynfw
rg3mHFSBdxoPE',
        accept: '*/*',
        referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' },
     rawHeaders:
      [ 'Host',
        'localhost:8080',
        'Connection',
        'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length',
        '51295521',
        'Origin',
        'http://evil.com/',
        'User-Agent',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64

Comment: c:\toolbox\pos-estate-data\oneops\ScoSopBackend>node app.js
Listening on port 8080
{ [Error: Unexpected field]
  code: 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE',
  field: 'uploads[]',
  storageErrors: [] }

Comment: Can you share client side for uploading file ?

Comment: upLoad() {
    let strSopName : string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("sopName")).value; 
    if(strSopName == "" || strSopName == null || strSopName == "Error you must enter a sop name"){
        strSopName = "Error you must enter a sop name"
        return;
    }
    
    this.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:8080/upload", [], this.filesToUpload).then((result) => {
        console.log(result); 
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    }); 

}

Comment: makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var formData: any = new FormData(); 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name); 
        }
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4){
                if(xhr.status == 200){
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                }

Comment: You are uploading multiple files. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035977/upload-multiple-files-with-xmlhttprequest-to-express-js-3-5-server for client side code and check my updated answer.